# How do I get back that app that I bought after reinstall?

Tags: release-loki, applications, appcenter

I bought a bunch of apps from Appcenter, but for reasons I had to reinstall my OS.

Is there any way for me to have those apps again without paying for them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the price and enter 0.